# Bootstrap max height/width when contents of div is different

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig, octobercms

I am looking to create a product feed per se, that has many images that are all aligned in rows and columns , so far if i force the max height to something small, and set object-fit: contain then it looks alright, however, if i make the screen size smaller it messes up and the individual divs become different sizes again, which leads to some being taller than others and eventually a lack of rows, or at least a lack of aligned rows.

i would put the maximum number of items in a row (large screen size, so 8) in a row but i am also unsure of how many rows i would need on a page because that is dynamic, i could then set a row to say 10% height.

also a problem is when landscape or portrait pictures sit next to each other due to the current nature of the site the landscape photos are the right size to view but are obviously shorter than average.

i guess what i am asking is there an easy way using only bootstrap/twig/php that does not require the server to download the image first which allows me to also set the height to say 200px when sm 400px when lg etc, but instead of pixels it maybe be 1 "set row height" for that viewport size...if i had only one viewport size this would've been done ages ago...

HTML/TWIG

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 productlistcontainer">
    <a href="../product?cat={{result.category_id}}&id={{result.product_id}}">
        <img src={{result.image_url}}    alt="product_image" class="productimages">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.productimages {
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
object-fit:contain;
}
```

thanks, any input is much appreciated,

-ALLW

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: i had my divs set strange, but after i sorted that i used width:100% height:100% background-cover:contain